# Slidetoogle and larger browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m using jquery slideToggle to show and hide a div on mobile devices. I’m using display: none inside a media query for devices below 768px. This allows the div to start closed .

If you resize the browser to be smaller than the 768px breakpoint, the Nav div disappears and you’re prompted with a Button to toggle it’s visibility. But if you resize the browser back to the original state (larger than 768px). At this point, you will notice the div remains hidden and does not return to display:block. Only after refreshing the browser will the div re-appear.

Could someone please suggest a method for solving this?

Comment: How about a media query for screens larger than 768px ? And the button should not set inline styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `$(window).resize` function

```
var _windowWidth = $(window).width();

$(window).resize( function() {
    if(_windowWidth > 768) {
        $("nav").show();
    }
});
```

Or make it visible with `css` if the screen is bigger than `768px`.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    nav {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Np, im glad i could help